# git log --follow, the gitpython way

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to access the commit history of a single file as in:

```
git log --follow -- <filename>
```

I have to use [gitpython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython), so what I am doing now is:

```
import git 
g = git.Git('repo_dir') 
hexshas = g.log('--pretty=%H','--follow','--',filename).split('\n')
```

then I build commit objects:

```
repo = git.Repo('repo_dir')
commits = [repo.rev_parse(c) for c in r]
```

Is there a way to do it in a more gitpython-ic way?
I tried both `commit.iter_parents()` and `commit.iter_items()`, but they both rely on `git-rev-list`, so they don't have a `--follow` option.

Comment: what is `r`? `repo`?

Answer (score 20):

For example,

With range time:

```
g = git.Git("C:/path/to/your/repo") 
loginfo = g.log('--since=2013-09-01','--author=KIM BASINGER','--pretty=tformat:','--numstat')
print loginfo
```

Output:

```
3       2       path/in/your/solutions/some_file.cs
```

You can see the added lines, removed lines and the file with these changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can try **[PyDriller](https://github.com/ishepard/pydriller)** instead (it uses GitPython internally). I'm the owner.

I created it so it's easier to use then other frameworks:

```
for commit in RepositoryMining("path_to_repo", filepath="here_the_file").traverse_commits():
    # here you have the commit object
    print(commit.hash)
```

Comment: You should probably be disclosing that you are the maintainer