# Finding first and last commit for every subfolder in directory

Tags: python, git

I need to loop over every folder in a directory and find the user responsible for the first and last commit. Is there any smart way to do this in git bash? I tried looking into this with the `subprocess` module in Python, and using that to loop through the folders, but not sure that is a good approach

What I have tried is

- `git log -- path/to/folder`**:** This solution just lists all commits to that subfolder. But I wish to filter only the first and last commit. I also wish to loop through all folders in the directory
- The replies in this stackoverflow thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759613/find-the-git-commit-where-directory-was-first-created): They didn't seem to work for me (either printing nothing, or giving an error)

Comment: Did you have a look at GitPython module? https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Also you might have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073154/git-log-follow-the-gitpython-way

Comment: At first glance it seems they focus on commit history for files, and not directories so it doesn't fully solve it for me. But I will have a more thorough look, thanks!

Comment: I thought it would work the same for directories, but I guess that was a misconception on my side.

Comment: Can you describe in more details what doesn't work with `git log -- path/to/folder` ?

Comment: Yes of course, edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in the current branch only, you can get the first commit via Git Bash with

```sh
git rev-list HEAD -- path/to/folder | tail -1
```

and the last commit with

```sh
git rev-list HEAD -- path/to/folder | head -1
```

[`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) is similar to `git log`, but it is a ["plumbing" command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain). "Plumbing" commands are a bit less user-friendly than "porcelain" commands like `git log`, but they are guaranteed to behave consistently regardless of your personal settings whereas "porcelain" commands may have different output depending on your config. Because of this, it's usually a good idea to use "plumbing" commands when writing scripts/programs.

`git rev-list` returns only the commit hash by default, but you can use `--pretty`/`--format` options similar to `git log`.

`head` and `tail` take a longer input—in this case, the entire list of commits for a path—and return only the first/last *n* lines, where *n* is  whatever number you give as the parameter. `git log` and `git rev-list` show the most recent commit first, so you need `tail` to get the first commit and `head` to get the last.

You could also get the last commit using

```sh
git rev-list HEAD -1 -- path/to/folder
```

without piping to `head`. However, you cannot get the first commit using Git's built-in commit-limiting options, because e.g.

```sh
git rev-list HEAD --reverse -1 -- path/to/folder
```

applies the `-1` limiter *first*, returning only the last commit, before applying `--reverse`.

Finally, it's worth noting that Git doesn't truly track directories, only files. If you create a folder with no files in it, it's not possible to commit that folder, and if you delete all the files within a folder, then as far as Git is concerned that folder doesn't exist anymore. The upshot is: these commands will get you the first and last commits that touch *any file within the directory* (and its subdirectories) as opposed to *the directory itself*. This distinction may or may not be important for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed reply, very useful to me

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with subprocess in the end

```
import subprocess
import os

dir_path = os.path.normpath('C:/folder_path')
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    subpath = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
    subprocess_args = ['git', 'log', "--pretty=format:{'author': '%aN', 'date': '%as', 'email': '%ce'}", subpath]
    commits = subprocess.check_output(subprocess_args).decode().split('\n')
    print(f'{f} -- first: {commits[-1]}, last: {commits[0]}')
```